# $(0,1)$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$ but not of $\Bbb R^2$ when we think of $\Bbb R$ as the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis

$(0,1)$ is an open subset of $R$ but not of $R^2$ when we think of $R$ as the x-axis in $R^2$.

How do I prove the above statement?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take say the point $P=(1/2,0)$ on the $x$-axis. Can you find an open (two dimensional) **disk** with centre $P$ that contains only points on the $x$-axis?

But certainly $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, since if you take any $a$ in this interval, there is an open **interval** that contains $a$ and is wholly contained in $(0,1)$.